# MySQL Construct a result with multiple results from other table

Tags: mysql

I admit it is a poor title, but I think this should clarify.  Let's say I have a vehicles table that looks like this

```
Vehicles

| vehicle_id | vehicle_name | vehicle_price |
| 1          | pinto        | 70000         |

Vehicle Options 

| vehicle_id | option_name  | option_value  |
| 1          | color        | red           |
| 1          | engine       | v8            |
```

How could I get all this back as one row... basically the vehicle row with the options appended to it.

```
| vehicle_id = 1 | vehicle_name = pinto | option_value = red | option_value(renamed) = V8 |
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the resulting table you wish; it isn't clear how you want to transform multiple rows into column(s).

Answer (score 0):

You want to `PIVOT` the records which MySQL doesn't not have default function on that. But you can still manually do it using `MAX()` and `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT  a.vehicle_id,
        a.vehicle_name,
        a.vehicle_price,
        MAX(CASE WHEN option_name = 'color' THEN option_value END) color,
        MAX(CASE WHEN option_name = 'engine' THEN option_value END) engine
FROM    Vehicles a
        INNER JOIN VehicleOptions b
            ON a.vehicle_id = b.vehicle_id 
GROUP   BY  a.vehicle_id,
            a.vehicle_name,
            a.vehicle_price
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/faf98/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════════╦══════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════╦════════╗
║ VEHICLE_ID ║ VEHICLE_NAME ║ VEHICLE_PRICE ║ COLOR ║ ENGINE ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╬════════╣
║          1 ║ pinto        ║         70000 ║ red   ║ v8     ║
╚════════════╩══════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════╩════════╝
```